# Changing color of the title block in poster template

Tags: beamer, titles, block, posters

I am trying to change the color of the title block in template [GeoURV Poster template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/geourv-poster-template/ygvdtpypxvrq). I know that i may change color in the beamerthemeGeoURV.sty. But I would like it to change in the gradient style, let's say from black to orange.

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the headline template like this (change the value in l. 9 to match the height of your headline as needed):

```
\input{preamble.tex}
\input{metadata.tex}

\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\foo}
\setlength{\foo}{8cm}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperwidth}{%
  color(0pt)=(black);
  color(\foo)=(col3)
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode
  
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\foo}
    \begin{pgfscope}
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\foo}}%
      \pgfusepath{clip}%
      \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}%
    \end{pgfscope}
  \end{pgfpicture}  
  \vskip-\foo

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \begin{columns}[T]
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.7\paperwidth}
        \vskip4ex
        \raggedright
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.25\paperwidth}
        \vskip8ex
        \begin{center}
          \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{figures/dgeo-apilat-color.png}
        \end{center}
        \vskip2ex
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vskip2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother


\useinnertheme[rounded]{tcolorbox}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  frame style={draw=col4,line width=2mm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] 

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you. But how can I rotate this, i.e., black at the bottom and orange at the top? I know I didn't specify this in my question. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much